# What does "hold bag" mean when traveling with easyJet?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, budget, terminology, easyjet

I will move to the Netherlands and am searching flights to select a price I can afford.

I found easyJet and since I am moving permanently I will have plenty of stuff with me. I am booking:

- a standard bag (25 * 20 * 45) that I can have on the plane
- the bag of my laptop (also on the plane)
- the rest of my stuff in two bags, one 27 kg, and one 11 kg

While booking, I found this

[image]

First of all is the meaning of "hold bag" the bag that I put in the check-in and the one that I await when arriving, in other words, the one that I don't take with me on the plane?

Second, that says that both should be 20 kg, but my case is one 27 kg and one 11 kg, will that work?

Comment: A [*cargo hold*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cargo_hold) is a compartment for stowing cargo during a voyage.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The hold luggage is the luggage that you check-in at the check-in / bag-drop counter when you arrive to the airport. It will not be accessible to you during the flight and you recover it at the luggage carousel after your arrival.

As written in [the excellent answer of @jcaron](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/77963/32134), easyjet allows you to pool your luggage allowance across bags and even persons on the same booking, as long as no bag is heavier than 32kg. (*You should consider accepting his answer instead of mine.*) In my old answer I had erroneously assumed this was not possible.

Note that in the drop-down menu one can also select heavier bags,

[image]

however their pricing scheme is such that it very quickly makes sense to add another bag instead of acquiring heavier luggage.

Regarding your intended cabin baggage, i.e. the bags you take with you on the plane, note that [easyjet only allows you one such item](http://www.easyjet.com/en/help/preparing-to-fly/baggage), and taking a separate laptop bag would incur a higher charge, unless you have paid for a premium fare.

Comment: thank you, but i remember my friends coming from out of Europe and all had bags bigger than 20 kg, maybe there are other airlines that allow me to pay but without selecting the number of bags? (i mean they just care about the altimate weight not the number of bags) do you know if any please?

Comment: @RERERERE we do not do recommendations here, other airlines have other rules but then they might not serve the connection you need. For easyjet the rules are as stated and I am pretty sure you can even out the weight distribution if you pack heavy stuff in the smaller bag or consider buying a cheap bag that allows you to put more stuff in the bag that is now the small one.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Easyjet explicitly allows you to pool your luggage allowance across items. See my answer for the link.

Comment: @jcaron thanks for pointing out, the downvote, which I assume is yours, is well-deserved. I have corrected my answer, pointing to yours (+1) and IMHO yours should be the accepted answer, I hope the OP comes back to do so.

Comment: @mts, downvote wasn't mine, though whoever made it now retracted it.

Comment: I can confirm you can split the weight over several bags, I've done it recently (last month).

Answer (score 8):

As other have explained, "hold luggage" is another term for "checked-in luggage", and designates luggage that will go into the hold of the plane (which you check-in/drop at the departure airport, and claim at the arrival airport).

**Easyjet allows you to pool your luggage allowance**. From [Easyjet's FAQ on Baggage](http://www.easyjet.com/en/help/preparing-to-fly/baggage?link=meganav):

> #### Can I pool my hold luggage allowance with other passengers on my booking?
>
> You can pool your total luggage weight allowance – across
> items and across customers – but an individual item cannot weigh more
> than 32 kg.
>
> So, each passenger with two items of 20kg hold luggage has a total
> weight allowance of 40kg. They could pool their luggage allowance by
> bringing one bag weighing 23kg and one bag weighing 17kg.
>
> OR
>
> Two passengers on the same booking, each with one 20kg item of hold
> luggage, have a total luggage allowance of 40kg. So they could pool
> their combined luggage allowance by bringing one bag weighing 22kg and
> one bag weighing 18kg.

Note that the 32kg limit is a hard limit. They will not, ever, allow you to check-in/drop a piece of luggage weighing more than 32kg (for the safety of baggage handlers).

It's not clear whether you could have more pieces of luggage than the number booked even if it fits in the total allowance in terms of weight, but in your case (1 piece 27kg and another 11kg), 2 x 20kg will definitely allow you to check-in those two pieces of luggage.

Answer (score 4):

"Hold" is originally a nautical term usually referring to a storage compartment below decks.

So, Hold Luggage to EasyJet is the same as Checked Baggage for every other airline.

I worked with a Brit a few years back who once said something like "I just send my luggage in the hold."  I remember because, while I understood it, to an American ear, it sounds strange.

Comment: than you, please do you know arilines that care just about the altimate weight not the number of bags? i can't have two bags with 20, the other is small

Comment: Isn't "hold luggage" the standard British term for this (i.e. not specific to Easyjet)?

Comment: BA uses checked baggage on their UK/English site.

Comment: Yes...sorry, I don't understand the comment.

Comment: I disagree.  Both BA and VS use Checked Baggage or Check in Baggage, along with all US carriers.  So, the far dominant English term is Checked Baggage.  Hold Baggage seems like a poor translation of the French usage, 'soute' being the equivalent of 'hold'.  Also, 'hold baggage' can easily be confused with 'please hold my baggage'.

Comment: @Johns-305: I can assure you that *hold baggage* is ordinary British English, not a poor translation from French or anything like that.  Maybe most airlines have standardised on *checked bags* these days, but in the past, I’m pretty *hold baggage/luggage* was the standard term on airlines flying from England — I remember the term *checked bag* being new and unfamiliar when I moved to the US in the early 2000’s, having previously flown often within Europe and to/from Aus, mostly with European airlines, KLM, and Qantas.

Comment: @Johns-305 Why French now? This is beginning to sound disingenuous... I put a question mark at the end of my earlier comment because I wasn't sure whether this usage was specifically British or universal there but “baggage hold” and “hold luggage” are certainly not terms that EasyJet made up. Also: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airliner#Baggage_holds)

Comment: I'm not saying that it's not proper English.  I even noted my co-worked from before.  I'm saying that the airlines have settled on Checked Baggage so by now, EasyJet is the outlier.  Aer Lingus and Ryanair use some form of Checked Baggage also.

Comment: I was responding to Relaxed.  Maybe Hold Baggage was the standard term, but seems not anymore.  All the majors, including Thompson, use Checked Baggage.

Comment: You were responding to me, so what? “Hold Baggage seems like a *poor* translation of the French usage” still implies it's not proper English, which is demonstrably false as has now been explained to you by three different people. I don't see how the fact that you actually intended it as a personal attack on my command of the English language makes it any better.

Comment: Whoa!  Take it easy friend.  "You asked: Isn't "hold luggage" the standard British term for this (i.e. not specific to Easyjet)?"  I'm merely pointing out that right now, it is not.  BA, VS, EI, FR, etc. all use a form of "Checked Baggage"  Of the majors, EasyJet is on it's own with Hold Luggage.

Comment: I was also responding to another comment about possible ambiguity with  checkered patters or security checks.  Sure, but in this case Hold Baggage might cause just as much ambiguity since it's no longer the dominant industry term, even for British airlines.  Hence the OP's question.

Comment: OK, makes more sense like that. But you've got to admit that “poor translation of the French usage” is not very plausible.

Comment: I, too, will certify that "hold luggage" is an absolutely standard piece of British English.  That said, it is hardly the weirdest piece of UK English the poor international traveller must deal with; consider HMG's adorable term for permission to stay in the country: *leave to remain*.  In general, it is a mistake to think that facility with American English qualifies one to navigate British English without considerable care; the converse is equally true.