# Vueling bags rules when buying extra weight

Tags: luggage, vueling

I am booking on Vueling and have chosen the Optima option, not the Basics one.

The Optima option allows me to have 23 kg on a checked bag, but I have two bags, one 27 kg and one 11 kg, and I want to buy extra weight.

When I want to buy the extra weight, they give me this screen (this is before selecting the extra weight)

[image]

As you see, the cost is zero and the allowed weight is 23kg, but after I select 2 suitcases (actually it is just one extra suitcase ), I get this screen

[image]

Having 46 kg is enough for me, but is there any strict limit on the number of bags as in Easyjet (see my [previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77945/what-does-hold-bag-mean-when-traveling-with-easyjet)) or can I have as many bags as I want as long as the weight is less than 46 kg?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each bag has to be below 23kg.

From the [Vueling website](http://www.vueling.com/en/vueling-services/prepare-your-trip/luggage) (click on "+ info" under the short text titled "I'm going to check in luggage"):

> On flights operated by Vueling, each passenger can check in a maximum
>   of 3 bags weighing up to 23kg per item. If the maximum allowance is
>   exceeded, at the airport you will be charged €12 for each excess kilo
>   per bag each way, up to a maximum of 32kg per bag each way.

And if you select two suitcases, you will only be allowed to check in two pieces, not more.